# Grandpa and Sports: Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle

I can never figure out why Grandpa likes and dislikes a lot of things, But sports?

> He likes Tennis but not Field Hockey
>
> He likes Football but not Baseball
>
> He likes Squash but not Bowling
>
> He likes _____eball but not _____

Fill in the blanks and tell me why

Note: While there could be several solutions for the blanks, only one solution for the why (at least as he told me). And yes, the "e" in the first blank is there in the word. Second blank does not have a restriction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think (thanks to @Cashbee for their partial solution — go upvote their answer!)

> Grandpa likes **Dodgeball** but not **Cricket**

This is because

> Tennis balls, Footballs, Squash balls, and Dodgeballs are all filled with air; to the best of my knowledge, Field Hockey balls, Baseballs, Bowling balls, and Cricket balls are not.

Comment: Still have to say why?

Comment: Ignore my comment please

Comment: @DEEM is this correct or should I keep thinking? :)

Comment: Correct it is. There is another solution also.

Comment: @DEEM Out of curiosity, would [rot13](https://rot13.com/)(qbqtronyy ohg abg tbys) be valid as well, or is there another aspect I'm missing?

Comment: cvpxyronyy naq tbys

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

> He likes **dodg**eball but not ____
> Because I cannot find another sport ending in `__eball` (except baseball but grandpa already said he doesn't like that). There are plenty of words like fireball, eyeball but they are no sport.

Comment: No no. The second blank has NO "e"

Comment: @DEEM I never said that. my partial answer is only about the first blank